# A conjecture about quadratic residues

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, congruences, quadratic-residues

Let $m$ be a positive integer, which is not a square of any other integer.

Then $x^2 \equiv m \pmod{m + 1}$ has no solution for any integer $x$.

It came up as an intermediate step in solution of a bigger problem. I've checked it numerically for the first few $m$, and it does seem to hold.

It's easily shown that the converse holds.

Comment: $m =12$, $8^2 = 5.13 - 1$

Comment: 4 is a square of 2, contrary to the assumption made.

Comment: @reuns, thanks, that's a good counterexample. Another one is

$5^2 \equiv 12 \pmod{12 + 1}$

Comment: For the $m$ that are prime, see https://oeis.org/A141293.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x^2 \equiv m \pmod{m+1}$, then, for some integer $n$,

\begin{align}
   x^2 &= m + (m+1)n \\
   x^2+1 &= (m+1)(n+1) \\
\end{align}

So we need to find $m$ and $n$ so that $x^2+1 = (m+1)(n+1)$ and $m$ or $n$ is not a perfect square.

---

\begin{array}{cc|ccc}
     x=5 & x^2+1 = 26 & m+1 &n+1 &m &n\\
\hline
&& 2 & 13 & \color{red}{1} & 12 \\
\hline
\end{array}

$$5^2\equiv 12 \pmod{13}$$

---

\begin{array}{cc|ccc}
     x=13 & x^2+1=170 & m+1 &n+1 &m &n\\
\hline
&& 2 & 85 & \color{red}{1} & 84\\
&& 5 & 34 & \color{red}{4} & 33\\
&& 10 & 17 & \color{red}{9} & \color{red}{16}\\
\hline
\end{array}

$$13^2\equiv 84 \pmod{85}$$
$$13^2\equiv 33 \pmod{34}$$

---

\begin{array}{cc|ccc}
     x=21 & x^2+1=442 & m+1 &n+1 &m &n\\
\hline
&& 2 & 221 & \color{red}{1} & 220\\
&& 13 & 34 & 12 & 33\\
&& 17 & 26 & \color{red}{16} & \color{red}{25}\\
\hline
\end{array}

$$21^2\equiv 220 \pmod{221}$$
$$21^2\equiv 33 \pmod{34}$$
$$21^2\equiv 12 \pmod{13}$$

---

Comment: It might help to add an example where the resulting values of $m$ are not all squares.

Comment: @BarryCipra - thanks. I added some useful answers.

Comment: I think you've got a typo in the first example: m + 1 should be 13, and n + 1 should be 2, then you get $5^2 \equiv 12 \pmod{13}$.

Also, it's sufficient that m is not a perfect square.

Comment: Oh I see, you want to swap n with m as required, it makes sense. It's a nice exposition.